# Corona + objects are not cleared between levels despite removeSelf + set to nil

Tags: object, coronasdk

I have multilevel game and all my objects stay 'empty' in memory between levels
what i mean is that if I set physics to hybrid, when i come again in the level, (or another level) it shows a box but without the picture. (and physics act on these empty boxes)
in the `destroyScene` I have made sure they are all

```
   myObj:removeSelf()
    myObj = nil
```

and i print a message to prove that it actually does it.

Also in the menu in the enterScene, just in case I do a

```
  local prior_scene = storyboard.getprevious()
  storyboard.purgescene( prior_scene )
```

and also tried a

```
  storyboard.removeAll()
```

and even a

```
  storyboard.purgeOnSceneChange = true
```

nothing works when i go to the next level, or into the same level again, all my previous objects are still here, I just don't get it

ok, it's gonna be a bit long but here the entire level. it does go through the destroyscene but somehow the display objects are not removed.

```
-- scene5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene5 = storyboard.newScene()

function scene5:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
  puppetJColCount = 0
  print ("createScene5", puppetJColCount)
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  CREATE display objects and add them to 'group' here.
    --  Example use-case: Restore 'group' from previously saved state.
    local physics = require("physics")
    physics.start()
    --physics.setScale(50)
    puppetT_outside = false
    puppetJ_outside = false

end -- scene -------------------------


-- set and release the catapult for puppetT
function arm_puppetT(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(puppetT)
        arming_puppetT = true
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        puppetT.x = event.x
        puppetT.y = event.y
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            puppetT:applyLinearImpulse(event.xStart - event.x, event.yStart - event.y, puppetT.x, puppetT.y)
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
            arming_puppetT = false
    end
end -- arm_puppetT ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function build_puppetT()
-- setup puppetT        
    puppetT = display.newImage("assets/t-head-57-78.png")
    puppetT.x = 80
    puppetT.y = 100
    physics.addBody(puppetT,"dynamic",{density=1.0, friction =0.3, bounce=0.2})
-- setup catapult event for arming puppetT
    puppetT:addEventListener("touch", arm_puppetT) 
end -- build_puppetT

function build_puppetJ_wall()
 puppetJColCount = puppetJColCount + 1  -- how many columns of puppetJ
    puppetJIJ = {}              -- define puppetJ as an array
    ij = 0
    ipuppetJtot = 0
--puppetJColCount = 1
    print ("build_puppetJ_wall puppetJColCount>" , puppetJColCount);
    for i=1, 4 do
        for j=1, puppetJColCount do
        ij = ij + 1         -- # of puppetJs on the screen
        ipuppetJtot = ipuppetJtot + 1
        puppetJIJ = display.newImageRect("assets/j-head-70-75.png",80,75)

        puppetJIJ.x = 600 + j*22
        puppetJIJ.y = 100 + (puppetJIJ.height /2 * (i -1))

        physics.addBody(puppetJIJ,"dynamic",{density=1.0,friction=0.3,bounce=0.2,isSensor=false,radius = var})
        end
    end
print ("building puppetJs #:" ,ipuppetJtot)
end -- build_puppetJ_wall -------------------------------------------------------------


function every_frame( event )
end -- every_frame --------------------------------------------------------------------

--reset level
function tap_reset_level(event)
        puppetT:applyLinearImpulse(0, 0, 0, 0)  -- stop the kick
        print "restarting physics?"
        puppetT:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )   -- stop the speed
    puppetT.x = 80
    puppetT.y = 100

    for ij = 1,ipuppetJtot do
        if (puppetJIJ) then
            puppetJIJ:removeSelf()
            puppetJIJ = nil ------
        end
    end
  puppetT:removeSelf()
  puppetT = nil

    build_puppetJ_wall()
  build_puppetT()

    puppetT_outside = false
    puppetJ_outside = false
    -- physics.addBody(puppetT,"dynamic",{density=1.0, friction =0.3, bounce=0.2})
    -- puppetT:addEventListener("touch", arm_puppetT)
    --physics.start()

end -- tap_reset_level -------------------------------------------------------------------------

function tap_main_menu(event)
print ("going to main menu")
  Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", every_frame)  
    for ij = 1,ipuppetJtot do
        if (puppetJIJ) then
            puppetJIJ:removeSelf()
            puppetJIJ = nil ------
        end
    end
    if (puppetT) then
        puppetT:removeSelf()
        puppetT = nil
    end


    -- scene5:exitScene(scene5)
    storyboard.gotoScene( "menu" )  
end --  tap_main_menu ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- ======================================================================================
-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene5:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  INSERT code here (e.g. start timers, load audio, start listeners, etc.)
--  group:insert( reset_btn )
-- load background
print ("enterScene scene5 " , puppetJtot)

    background = display.newImage("assets/parliament-1200-800.png",0,0)
--create reset level button
    reset_btn = display.newImageRect( "assets/btn_reset_128.png", 50,50)
    reset_btn.x = 50
    reset_btn.y = 50

--create main menu button
    main_menu_btn = display.newImageRect( "assets/btn_home_128.png", 50,50)
    main_menu_btn.x = 100
    main_menu_btn.y = 50

-- show the level
    local myText = display.newText( "Level 5", display.contentWidth - 60, 50,  "Helvetica", 24 )
    myText:setTextColor(255, 255, 255)

--  insert(floor);

    floor = display.newRect(20,display.contentHeight - 40,display.contentWidth - 40 ,10)
    physics.addBody(floor,"static",{density=1.0, friction =-0.3,bounce=-0.2,isSensor=false})

-- build puppetT
  build_puppetT()


print ("width=" , display.contentWidth , "height=",display.contentHeight)


-- setup puppetJs
    build_puppetJ_wall()

-- everything happens in everyframe function
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", every_frame)

--add reset event
    reset_btn:addEventListener( "tap", tap_reset_level ) 
--add mainmenu event
    main_menu_btn:addEventListener( "tap", tap_main_menu )  
end -- scene:enterScene ----------------------------------------------------------------
-- ======================================================================================


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene5:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view
print "scene:exitScene5"
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --  INSERT code here (e.g. stop timers, remove listeners, unload sounds, etc.)
end -- exitScene


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene5:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", every_frame)
    puppetJColCount = 0

    if (reset_btn) then
print ("destroyScene5 - removing tap_reset_level")
        reset_btn:removeEventListener( "tap", tap_reset_level ) 
        reset_btn:removeSelf()
    end
        reset_btn = nil
    if (main_menu_btn) then
        main_menu_btn:removeEventListener( "tap", tap_main_menu )
        main_menu_btn:removeSelf()
    end
        main_menu_btn = nil
    for ij = 1,ipuppetJtot do
        if (puppetJIJ) then
            puppetJIJ:removeSelf()
        end
            puppetJIJ = nil ------
    end

    if (puppetT) then
    puppetT:removeSelf()

  end
    puppetT = nil

 scene5 = nil

end -- destroyScene ------------------------------------------------------------



scene5:addEventListener( "createScene", scene5 )

scene5:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene5 )

scene5:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene5 )

scene5:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene5 )

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene5
```

---

update:

Hi @DevfaR

Ha, I have restarted from scratch with the corona template and figured out a few things:

1) the exitScene/destroyScene actually does something if the local group is used to group display objects. it removes the display group !
not really obvious as there is only one declaration in it, no code as such

2) the reason why I had so much of removeSelf of objects all over the place is because nothing was working. So I tried pretty much everything under the web.

3) And the reason why it didnt work is because I was creating my display objects into a function. and somehow the display group is not passed there. if I move the code into the createScene function then indeed it  is all cleared up when going to the next scene.

problem is .. I really would like to group my puppetCreation code !
e.g.

```
function scene:createScene( event )
        local group = self.view
        local physics = require("physics")
        physics.start()
        background = display.newImage("assets/bckg.png",0,0)
    group:insert(background)

       createPuppet1(group)
       createPuppet2(group)
end
function createPuppet1(group)
        puppet1= display.newImage("assets/puppet1.png",0,0)
    group:insert(puppet1)
end
function createPuppet2(group)
        puppet2= display.newImage("assets/puppet2.png",0,0)
    group:insert(puppet2)
end
```

I passed (group) because the function createPuppet doesnt let me specify
local group = self.view

my email address is edualczatebed@gmail.com

thank you for your help

Comment: can you include more code it's hard to point out where your problem occurred just by giving a snippet of it

Answer (score 0):

there's a lot of bug in your code the way you implement it is not good because when you go to a scene and then you switch to another scene your removing all of the object on the `destroyScene` together with it's listener which is not very efficient  i cannot point out what's causing the problem because like i said there is a lot of bug in your code. i think you didn't quite understand how to use a storyboard on Corona. to give you an idea on how will you solve your problem i will implement some code for you to understand that even if you do not remove the object on `destroyScene` you can remove the object via it's on display groups.

```
local rectangle
local circle

local function nextScene(event)
  storyboard.gotoScene( "scene_2", "fade", "500")

end

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    rectangle = display.newRect(100,100,100,100)
    rectangle:setFillColor(255,0,0)
    rectangle.x = 100
    rectangle.y = 100

    circle = display.newCircle(100,100,50)
    circle.x = 250
    circle.y = 100
    circle:setFillColor(0,255,0)

    --inserting all of your object into display group so that if you destroy the scene the display group will be remove
    group:insert(rectangle) 
    group:insert(circle)


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end


-- Called immediately after scene has moved onscreen:
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    rectangle:addEventListener("tap", nextScene)
    circle:addEventListener("tap", nextScene)



    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end


-- Called when scene is about to move offscreen:
function scene:exitScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end


-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (display group)
function scene:destroyScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------



    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

end
```

as you can see i create 2 object the rectangle and circle after i created the objects insert it to group then on `enterScene` i added a tap listener which will go to the second scene if i tap the object. notice that i didn't bother to remove the object and listener on `destroyScene` when i go to the scene_2 that is because when i insert the object to the display group whenever i change the scene it will always remove the object. so after moving to the next scene you can either purged the last scene or completely remove it so when you get back to that scene it will recreate the object.
hope this can help you solve your problem

Comment: Hi @DevfaR.
that is correct, I dont really understand how to use a storyboard because there is no tutorial out there. only bits of code and workaround by forums. so your help is VERY MUCH appreciated, believe me.

Comment: Now, what you say is very interesting: 
 "notice that i didn't bother to remove the object and listener on destroyScene when i go to the scene_2 that is because when i insert the object to the display group whenever i change the scene it will always remove the object" is that so ? why is there no destroy_scene ?

Comment: just before going to work, trying to make your code work by putting it straight into my level5.lus, here are my questions.. 
my level5.lua is called from menu.lua

do I need to have 
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

at the beginning of each 'levelx.lua' ? 
(because just like this it doesnt work) = I get a scene5.lua:16 attempt to index global 'scene' (a nil value)

Comment: i added the destroyScene on the code below exitScene. about your question if you need to use storyboard on every level yes you need to use storyboard for switching different layout thats why if you create a new project with storyboard there is a scene template generated. it's to long for me to explain all the function in story board try to understand how it works go to this link 
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/
if you have question just ask on here

Comment: believe it or not I went over this documentation about 10 times. it doesnt explain why we need to add this 'local group = self.view' into every function ? (do we ?) what it does and how ?
does it make all the objects of the scene get removed when the exit_scene  is called ?
same for function scene:createScene( event )
Am I supposed to call scene:.. or scene1:   scene2: ..  for each level (scene1.lua, scene2.lua)
there are so many things that are not explained, that I was hoping you would. Someone would.
thanks anyway

Comment: yes you must use group view if you want to remove the object i can send you sample code on how to implement the storyboard just send me your email address